# Axios fail to install on Firebase Function with nodejs 14

Tags: node.js, firebase, npm, axios, google-cloud-functions

I am using Firebase Functions and trying to install and use axios. when I do `npm install` to install the package as below. I have no idea why it is failing. On run time I do not see any logs etc.

**Command:**

```
npm i axios
```

**I got below error:**

```
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: undefined,
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '14' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v16.6.1', npm: '7.20.3' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
```

This is when I am trying it for Firebase Functions

Comment: I'm having the same issue here, the error showed up, then i found axios in the dependencies, just ignored it and deployed successfully.

Answer (score 1):

When you run the command `firebase init functions` it creates files(including the `package.json`) and folder name `functions`. Inside the `package.json` there's a **`"engines"`** which already specify the version of `nodejs`that currently is version **14**.

If you are installing locally the `axios` make sure that you change the version of your **`"engines"`** inside the `package.json` according to the node version that you are using locally. For your case it should be:

**package.json**:

```
"engines": {
    "node": "16"
  }
```

Comment: well i m not caring locally what it installs. the behavior i am seeing is that axios API call is not happening on the firebase functions. i don't see it in the logs.

Comment: double check if  the `axios` is included in your `"dependencies"` inside `package.json`

Comment: it is included in the package.json

Comment: It seems this is another issue, if not can you include how to reproduce your issue. I have the same issue based on the error and fixed it using my answer.

Comment: I'm having the same issue here, the error showed up, then i found axios in the dependencies, just ignored it and deployed successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Are all you sure about if your finding the correct package.json file? I had this problem too and I discover, after hours, a 8th layer issue.